# How to Split the box plot of a variable with several levels

Tags: boxplot

How can I modify this code to make the space between second and third levels on the box plot. I mean, I want to spit the box plot into two section, a and b on right side and c on the left side.

```
   library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(group=sample(c("a","b","c"),100,replace=T),x=rnorm(100),y=rnorm(100)*rnorm(100))
xlabs <- paste(levels(df$group),"\n(N=",table(df$group),")",sep="")
ggplot(df,aes(x=group,y=x,color=group))+geom_boxplot()+scale_x_discrete(labels=xlabs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add new variable for facetting in `ggplot`.

```
df$facets <- ifelse(df$group == "a" | df$group == "b", "ab", "c")
```

Now plot with `facet_grid` and modified `scale_x_dsicrete`.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=group,y=x,color=group)) +
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_grid(~ facets, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = levels(df$group), labels = xlabs)
```

*If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.*